# Is there any difference between es6 map and immutable.js map?

Tags: ecmascript-6, immutable.js, es6-map

I am new to immutable.js. Is there any difference between map from immutable.js and map from ES6? If there is no difference, why do we need to use immutable.js?

### immutable.js

```
const { Map } = require('immutable')
const map1 = Map({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })
const map2 = map1.set('b', 50)
map1.get('b') // 2
map2.get('b') // 50
```

### ES6

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(NaN, 'not a number');
myMap.get(NaN); // "not a number"
```

Comment: Only one of them is immutable?

Comment: Here's a clue: `const map2 = map1.set('b', 50); console.log(map1.get('b'));`  Try that in both.

Answer (score 9):

When you run set on an Immutable.js map, modifying the data it contains, it will have a different address in memory.  That means that `map1 !== map2` in your first example, whereas the same code might say that they're the same when using ES6 maps.

The reason people really care about Maps with different data coming up as `!==` is that tools like React, Flux, & Redux all depend on quickly checking whether anything has changed in the state.  The `===` is the fastest check you can use for that, but it's essentially comparing the memory addresses of the references on both sides.

If you change the contents of that object, the memory address might still be the same, because Javascript uses shallow copies for performance reasons.  Immutable.js guarantees, well, immutability -- an object cannot be changed.  If you change the map, now it's a new map.  That means the `===` comparison always comes up correct.

If you're not using one of those state management libraries and are just using Immutable.js because it's trendy, then you might not have to!  Even if you are using those libraries, there are other ways of guaranteeing immutability --- I've found that [`dot-prop-immutable`](https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable) delivers the functionality I need and with less overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Map in ES6 is not immutable.
Following is screenshot from chrome console where I am using es6 map

[image: output for map immutability]